# Server selection Timeout error-Mangodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, jupyter-notebook

I Started learning MongoDB atlas recently,and was trying to connect it with Jupyter notebook. im facing Server selection timeout error, and I’m unable to resolve it.
help me get rid of this. Im new to this arena,so,in need of basic explanation.

> ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
> cluster0-shard-00-02.gl4co.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has
> expired (_ssl.c:1125),cluster0-shard-00-00.gl4co.mongodb.net:27017:
> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
> certificate has expired
> (_ssl.c:1125),cluster0-shard-00-01.gl4co.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has
> expired (_ssl.c:1125), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description:
> <TopologyDescription id: 621f7d6cb87ad4090bfca8ca, topology_type:
> ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription
> ('cluster0-shard-00-00.gl4co.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type:
> Unknown, rtt: None,
> error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-00.gl4co.mongodb.net:27017:
> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
> certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1125)')>, <ServerDescription
> ('cluster0-shard-00-01.gl4co.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type:
> Unknown, rtt: None,
> error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-01.gl4co.mongodb.net:27017:
> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
> certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1125)')>, <ServerDescription
> ('cluster0-shard-00-02.gl4co.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type:
> Unknown, rtt: None,
> error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-02.gl4co.mongodb.net:27017:
> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
> certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1125)')>]>

Comment: isn't the error already obvious? Your certificate expired. Generate a new one at mongodb console. The menu on the left, choose Database Access, and create a new user, or generate a new certificate for your existing user.

Comment: is it about user. because i tried creating a new one. didn't work out. let me know if there is an alternative